# How can I add error trapping to this method?

Tags: java, arraylist

The method I want to add error trapping to is :

```
private void DealCard() {
    Card c = deck.removeTopCard();
    onTable.add(c);
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

It allows you to press a case in the GUI, and then prints a single card out on the deck (table array list). You can keep pressing this case to deal more cards from the deck. How can I add error trapping so that once the deck of all 52 cards has been dealt, it brings up a message such as "whole deck dealt", because currently it just breaks after you deal all the cards and then attempt to deal another one.

Comment: the error trapping could begin inside `removeTopCard()` which should imo return `null` if there is no card to remove.  Then if `c` is `null` show your message

Comment: Why don't you just consider to add a method to count remaining cards of deck and testing this value before removing a new card ?

Comment: Thanks, will keep options open with it but the try statement below seems to handle the problem easily enough.

Comment: Also just to let you know the downvotes are because many think there's lack of research effort as it is a basic question, but I understand it's hard to research on concepts you do not know the terms for. Error handling is a better term than error trapping. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want a `if` condition that checks the number of card you have inside the `deck` (which I assume if an arraylist of `Card`) to see if you have anymore cards. Here's an example:

```
private void DealCard() {

  if(!deck.isEmpty())
  {
     Card c = deck.removeTopCard();
     onTable.add(c);
     System.out.println(c);
  }
  else 
  {
     //print something to notify user that the decks is empty, or someother form of handling.
  }
}
```

Another option is to put the if-else conditional inside the `removeTopCard()` method, this is more of a programming principle where you have [Seperation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) that ensure one method does only one thing, and checking for empty decks might be a job for `removeTopCard()`, this is your choice, though.

I would recommend doing error checking rather than catching/throwing exceptions as one should only throw errors when they are **truly exceptional**, having an empty deck seems like an issue you'll run into fairly often, and not a super special case, so you should handle it. Throwing exceptions are costly, which might not matter to you if you're just a beginner and starting out, (classes I took don't really care) but you want to think about this if you'll be programming in the long run. [Here's an SO question with more information on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29763061/returning-true-or-false-or-throwing-an-exception/29763305#29763305). You might want to read up more about concepts such as if-else conditionals, handling exceptions and null values and what not for additional knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, will look into the differences!

Answer (score 0):

```js
private void DealCard() {

  try {
      Card c = deck.removeTopCard();
      onTable.add(c);
      System.out.println(c);
  } catch(Exception ex) {
      // handle the exception here
  }

}
```

Comment: @lewisRossiterlk using a `try-catch` statement here is awful.

Comment: Yeah, I've changed it the the if else statement that I accepted as the answers :).